# PHP - Preg Match All - Wordpress Multiple short codes with multiple parameters

Tags: php, preg-match-all

I'm trying to find a regex capable of capturing the content of short codes produces in Wordpress.

My short codes have the following structure:
[shortcode name param1="value1" param2="value2" param3="value3"]

The number of parameters is variable.

I need to capture the shortcode name, the parameter name and its value.

The closest results I have achieved is with this:

```
/(?:\[(.*?)|\G(?!^))(?=[^][]*])\h+([^\s=]+)="([^\s"]+)"/
```

If I have the following content in the same string:

```
[specs product="test" category="body"]

[pricelist keyword="216"]

[specs product="test2" category="network"]
```

I get this:

```
0=>array(

    0=>[specs product="test"
    1=> category="body"
    2=>[pricelist keyword="216"
    3=>[specs product="test2"
    4=> category="network")

1=>array(
    0=>specs
    1=>
    2=>pricelist
    3=>specs
    4=>)
2=>array(
    0=>product
    1=>category
    2=>keyword
    3=>product
    4=>category)
3=>array(
   0=>test
   1=>body
   2=>216
   3=>test2
   4=>network)
   )
```

I have tried different regex models but I always end up with the same issue, if I have more than one parameter, it fails to detect it.

Do you have any idea of how I could achieve this?

Thanks
Laurent

Comment: What is the _exact_ array output you expect here?

Comment: But it does match all the parts that you want right? https://regex101.com/r/v8l4X9/1

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The first array is broken array[0][1] should be part of array[0][0] while array[0][1] should be empty like array[1][1]

Comment: @Thefourthbird yes, it does but the first array is broken, there should be only two elements in the first array (array[0])

Comment: @Laurent I had written a variant of the pattern https://3v4l.org/6FbEO Or do you mean literally just 2 entries in the first subarray?

Comment: @Thefourthbird thanks! yes, there should only be 3 matches for the first array, one for each full match. I know it may look a bit trivial but it's annoying to code exceptions just because the matching is broken.

Comment: @Laurent Perhaps you could use 3 arrays, where the first has the shortcode names, and the second and third have the keys and the values. https://3v4l.org/RdRro

Comment: @Thefourthbird ah, that's nice, you're right, I should probably looking for this kind of alternative instead of ending up with an unreadable regex. I'll give it a try!

Comment: @Thefourthbird if you post this as an answer instead of a comment, I'll accept it as a solution, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make use of the `\G` anchor using 3 capture groups, where capture group 1 is the name of the shortcode, and group 2 and 3 the key value pairs.

Then you can remove the first entry of the array, and remove the empty entries in the 1st, 2nd and 3rd entry.

This is a slightly updated pattern

```
(?:\[(?=[^][]*])(\w+)|\G(?!^))\h+(\w+)="([^"]+)"
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4HaB6W/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/RdRro)

Example

```
$s = '[specs product="test" category="body"]';
$pattern = '/(?:\[(?=[^][]*])(\w+)|\G(?!^))\h+(\w+)="([^"]+)"/';

$strings = [
    '[specs product="test" category="body"]',
    '[pricelist keyword="216"]',
    '[specs product="test2" category="network" key="value"]'
];

foreach($strings as $s) {
    if (preg_match_all($pattern, $s, $matches)) {
        unset($matches[0]);
        $matches = array_map('array_filter', $matches);
        print_r($matches);
    }
}
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => specs
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => product
            [1] => category
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => test
            [1] => body
        )

)
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => pricelist
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => keyword
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 216
        )

)
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => specs
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => product
            [1] => category
            [2] => key
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => test2
            [1] => network
            [2] => value
        )

)
```